# infinite intersection of a collection of sets

Tags: real-analysis

We have a collection of subsets E(n) of R where E(n) is closed when n is odd and open when n is even. As well, E(n+1) is a subset of E(n) for each n. What is the intersection of all the E(n)'s in this collection? (n is natural number.)

I used an example of (-1/n,1/n) and [-1/n,1/n] to see it has only one point but couldn't come up with an argument. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be multiple possible answers to "What is the intersection of all the $E(n)$ in this collection?"

Consider:

- $E(n) = \left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$ when $n$ is even and $E(n) = \left[-\frac1n,\frac1n\right]$  when $n$ is odd; the intersection is $\{0\}$
- $E(n) = \left(a-\frac1n,b+\frac1n\right)\cup \left(c-\frac1n,d+\frac1n\right)$ when $n$ is even and $E(n) = \left[a-\frac1n,b+\frac1n\right] \cup  \left[c-\frac1n,d+\frac1n\right]$  when $n$ is odd; the intersection is $[a,b]\cup [c,d]$
- $E(n) = \emptyset$ when $n$ is even and $E(n) = \emptyset$  when $n$ is odd; the intersection is $\emptyset$
- $E(n) = \mathbb R$ when $n$ is even and $E(n) = \mathbb R$  when $n$ is odd; the intersection is $\mathbb R$

As Pedro Freire said in the comments, all answers must be closed subsets of $\mathbb R$ as the intersection of closed sets, and any closed subset of $\mathbb R$ can be a solution by taking balls round it as in the first couple of examples

Comment: Yes, it seems $E = \cap_n E(n)$ can be any closed set $C$; with $E_0(n)$ being the example given by OP of vanishing balls on the origin, $E(n) = C + E_0(n)$ always verifies the hypothesis.

Comment: And the intersection has to be closed, since $E = \cap_n E(n) = \cap_n E(2n + 1)$, which is the intersection of closed sets, and the intersection of closed sets is closed.